# jquery hover on item stuck in infinite loop/starts blinking items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see my code below. All I want is:

- All my items are absolutely positioned
- when I hover on item1, I want item2, item3 to show
- when I hover on item2, I want item3 to hide
- When I click on item2, I perform some function when item3 is still hidden

With my code below, if I hover on item2, it starts blinking item2 and item3.

What am I doing wrong?

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/53/

HTML

```
<div class="item1">
  item1
</div>
<div class="item2">
    item2
</div>
<div class="item3">
    item3
</div>
```

CSS:

```
item1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:red;
    top:5%;
}

.item3, .item2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    top:8%;
    left:1%;
    display:none;
}

.item3 {
    top:18%;
}
```

JS:

```
var item1 = $(".item1");
var item2 = $(".item2");
var item3 = $(".item3");

item1.hover(
    function() {
      item2.show();
      item3.show();
    },
    function() {
      item2.hide();
      item3.hide();
    }

);

item2.hover(
    function() {
      item3.hide();
    },
    function() {
    }

);

item2.click(
    function() {
        alert("Perform some function");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="item1">
  item1
    <div class="item2">
        item2
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
        item3
    </div>
</div>
```

you should restruct your html

item2 is out of item1 so when you move on item2, item1's mouseleave will trigger then trigger item1's mouseenter

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an event listener, otherwise your code is just running through top down.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to restructure your HTML you could write another function for onhover on item3

```
item3.hover(
function() {
     item2.show();
  item3.show();
},
function() {
}
```

);

http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/55/

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

increase z-index of item1, or just move item2+3 to anywhere else